# When the explorer detached the dll which is for shell namespace extension on win Xp?

Tags: dll, windows-shell

I found that:
  the dll was detached(process) when I close the window(opend shell namespace externsion), but sometime didn't.

There are some global object in my dll. so, I want to find out when the dll be detached(process).

Comment: Can you provide some more info...?

Comment: The dll was writen for shell namespace externsion. The explorer load(attached) it when browsing namespace on first time. A dll had been attached must be detached. So i want to know when it will be detached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you export the [`DllCanUnload`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms690368%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function from your DLL you will be called when Explorer wants to unload your DLL. You can block it if you want, or perform some clean-up before allowing the unload.